# Add a launcher in Plank for a different (static) version of an installed program

Tags: plank

I need to test from time to time the beta (static portable) builds of a program -- the stable version of which is also installed (from deb) - namely [Deadbeef](https://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/files/).

I want to keep a launcher of the static beta build in Plank panel, but after selecting 'keep in dock' and restarting, the version launched is the main stable one.

How to add to Plank a launcher for the static version of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Plank needs `.desktop` files in order to launch a program.**

The Plank launchers are specified in `~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/`, for each item there is a `.dockitem` file which contains lines like

```
[PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///path/to/the/desktop-file.desktop
```

For example, dragging&dropping the `usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop` file onto Plank will create the corresponding file `~/.config/plank/dock1/launchers/vlc.dockitem` with the lines:

```
[PlankItemsDockItemPreferences]
Launcher=file:///usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop
```

So, for the given case of a static build, a `.desktop` file is needed containing the line

Exec=/path/to/the/static/executable

When a main version is already installed, like in my case with Deadbeef, a simple way is to copy the `usr/share/applications/deadbeef.desktop` file in an accessible location, edit it in a text editor, change the `Exec=` line as above, save, and then drop the desktop file onto Plank.